# Angular Material Modules are not recognized

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular5, angular-material2

I wasted a lot of time on this mistake, I'm starting new angular5 project and I want to use angular material.
I imported and exported the material modules in a material.module.ts file:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { MatIconModule,MatButtonModule,MatSidenavModule,MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatToolbarModule,

  ],
  exports: [
    MatIconModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatSidenavModule,
    MatToolbarModule
  ],
  declarations: []
})
export class MaterialModule { }
```

then I imported the material.module inside app.module:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { FlexLayoutModule } from "@angular/flex-layout";
import { MasterPageModule } from './master-page/master-page.module';
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { MaterialModule } from './material.module';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    CommonModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    MasterPageModule,
    MaterialModule

  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],

})
export class AppModule { }
```

When I try too use `<mat-toolbar> </mat-toolbar> I` got the common error:

```
Template parse errors:'mat-toolbar' is not a known element:
1. If 'mat-toolbar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'mat-toolbar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.
```

**Update**
 package.Json

```
{
  "name": "front-end-app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build --prod",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.2.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^5.0.0-beta.14",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^5.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.2.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.6",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.19"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "~1.7.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.3",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~4.1.0",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.5.3"
  }
}
```

I cant see where is the mistake! any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your code works for me. How's your package.json?

Comment: @bugs I updated the question, please take a look at package.Json

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must import the `MaterialModule` in every module in which the material components are used in.

That means that if one of the components in your `MasterPageModule` uses the `<mat-toolbar>`, you must import the material module in that module as well. It's not enough to import it in just `app.module`.

Also do not import `BrowserModule` in your `MaterialModule`. Import `CommonModule` instead. See the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#should-i-import-browsermodule-or-commonmodule) for the detailed explanation.

> Do not import BrowserModule in any other module. Feature modules and lazy-loaded modules should import CommonModule instead. They need the common directives. They don't need to re-install the app-wide providers.

See the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/ngmodule-faq#should-i-import-browsermodule-or-commonmodule) for the detailed explanation.

Comment: thanks, I removed the BrowserModule, but for test purpose I'm placing the  <mat-toolbar> into app.component.html and still not working, I think  that's means that my application is not recognizing the material modules.

Comment: I posted my package.json too, please take a look at it.

Comment: everything looks ok, try removing package-lock.json, node_modules and   run `npm install` again

Comment: no need for that, once I removed the BrowserModule and recompiled the project every thing goes fine. Thank you alot :) .

Comment: Glad I could help :)